# error whilst passing values between activities

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an activity which has an edit text which becomes visible when a button is clicked. I fill the edit text up and click another button. On clicking this button the edit text content must be sent to another activity.The first activity takes the edit text and queries a list of data from my Parse database and shows it in a ListView in the Second Activity.But whenever i click the first button(after entering the string) the app crashes.This is the first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String name;
    EditText search;
    Button g;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpSpinners();
        Parse.initialize(this, "AAh5US7zhbYyFBexsv07cjo34ZZiB7KNe9SuTv7e",
                "eKUG1pYaV50hVyDC9d4qZc4qf1dCtOTqnX92eGJV");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Go);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void byName(View v) {
        search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        search.requestFocus();
        g.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void Go(View v) {
        name = search.getText().toString();
        final Intent i;
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResterauntList1.class);
        i.putExtra("restrauntName", name);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

In the above byName is the onClick for making the EditText visible, and Go is the onClick for getting my EditText string and passing it to the next activity. The second activity is below

```
public class ResterauntList1 extends Activity {
    String rValue;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list1);

        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        rValue = bdl.getString("restrauntName");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);
        populateList(rValue, "name");

    }

    private void populateList(final String Value, final String Key) {
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("resdb");
                query.whereEqualTo(Key, Value);
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("name");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResterauntList1.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Searching for " + Value);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restListView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ParseObject object = (ParseObject) listView
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                String Id = object.getObjectId();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleRestraunt.class);
                i.putExtra("restId", Id);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.resteraunt_list1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The error as stated above occurs when I click the Go button.The error is

```
09-02 14:58:46.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3061): Process: com.example.gastronomaapp, PID: 3061
09-02 14:58:46.443: E/AndroidRuntime(3061): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gastronomaapp/com.example.gastronomaapp.ResterauntList1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any idea where I am making a mistake? The funniest thing almost the same code has worked in another part of my app. absolutely clueless whats wrong.

Comment: Why do you `setContentView` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        rValue = bdl.getString("restrauntName");
```

change to

```
    rValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntName");
```

You put the string directly on the intent, not packaged in a bundle.

Comment: Getting an error saying the getIntent is undefined for Bundle. This was on changing to your code. EDIT Just figured it out. I made it        rValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntName"); and it worked like a charm. Thanks a ton man